# R: color first 100 observations different than second 100 observations

Tags: r, colors

I have 200 observations with 6 features each, and I am trying to color the first 100 observations a different color than the second 100 observations.  This is for principal component analysis.  I have to insert some code with "col" inside my code but I do not know how to do this.  Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
biplot(pr.out,scale=0,col=?)
```

Comment: Please provide some toy data, the result of `dput(head(pr.out))` can be of help. Also, show what you have tried and what specific problems you have faced.

Comment: Hi Math, I want to reiterate what PavoDive said. It is much easier for people to help if you provide a minimum reproducible example. What that means is, we can cut and paste your data and your code into our own R sessions, and run it to get the same error you are getting stuck on. Then can provide our own solutions to help you get unstuck. Without the complete code to cut and paste, it can be difficult to imagine the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above comments are good advice, but the answer to your question is that you cannot use more than one color for the observations in the version of `biplot` in the `stats` package (see manual pages `?biplot.prcomp` and `?biplot.default`). You can use different symbols however:

```
PCA <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
sym <- c(rep("x", 25), rep("o", 25))
biplot(PCA, scale=0, xlabs=sym)
```

[image: Biplot]